# What's the difference between "riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc" and "riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc"

Tags: operating-system, cross-compiling

I want to develop a tiny OS on risc-v, and when I downloaded the risc-v cross-compiler, I found out that there are two modes of compiler, "riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc" and "riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc".
I would like to know the difference between the two compilers.

I found that I should choose "riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc" because the OS is essentially a bare-metal program. But I'm not sure what exactly the difference is between these two compilers.
I also learned something about the concepts of "newlib" and "glib", but I didn't recognize what they do.

Comment: That identifies what kind of system the compiler targets. But in all honesty, if these terms are new to you, an OS (even a tiny one) may be a very high reach. That is very difficult. I would advice to start with some easier projects, like small C programs and small assembly programs.